# DCount in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table that I would like to perform a counting operation to summarize its contents.  The DCount function should work, but I cannot get the syntax correct even though it appears to match examples that I have found online.
Table: tblIGEMS
Field to Sum from: Squadron

VBA Formula:

```
DCount("[Squadron]", "tblIGEMS", "[Squadron] = xyz")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to match against a field named `xyz`? Or are you trying to match against the string value `"xyz"`? If the latter, then you need to escape quotation marks within the expression: `DCount("[Squadron]", "tblIGEMS", "[Squadron] = 'xyz'")`, or `DCount("[Squadron]", "tblIGEMS", "[Squadron] = ""xyz""")` (see [here](https://github.com/zspitz/VBA-content/blob/eef7d8a5ad1a24f7f66c64b129d96de7d5580032/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/string-data-type.md))

Answer (score 3):

If xyz is fixed:

```
DCount("*", "tblIGEMS", "[Squadron] = 'xyz'")
```

If xyz is a variable in code:

```
DCount("*", "tblIGEMS", "[Squadron] = '" & xyz & "'")
```

If xyz is a field:

```
DCount("*", "tblIGEMS", "[Squadron] = '" & [xyz] & "'")
```

If xyz is a control on a form:

```
DCount("*", "tblIGEMS", "[Squadron] = '" & [Forms]![YourFormName]![xyz] & "'")
```

If Squadron is numeric, remove the single-quotes.

Comment: Thank you very much!  "XYZ" is the text I will change for the different units, your solution worked perfectly